# ionic 2 destination path

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic2

There is my destination adress from `map-page.ts` and i want to get path from 
Where I am , what i must do .

```
initMap(){
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
        let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter()
  });

  let content = this.msj;          

  this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex.

Comment: Yes i see this and i try it but i cant use this service in ionic 2...

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a basic ionic-2 app for showing path between 2 places, taking functions from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex).
Please see this [example](https://github.com/math10/GoogleMapPath).